# Store files and comments for a web application. Table design

Tags: sql, database-design, web-applications, architecture

I have a web appliaction with several entities (tables).Each one has his CRUD pages.

I'd like to add for some the, the ability to add comments and attach files.

I was thinking of two scenarios.

1. One table for all comments/files - table would have some id for the entity and the particular record.
2. For each entity a separate comments/files table.

The files would be stored on the disk in a directory.In the table would be the name of the file and some additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tradeoff. With a **single comments table**, you get a simple, DRY (don't repeat yourself) schema, but you don't get foreign key constraints and thus no cascade deletion.  Thus, if you delete an entity with comments, you must also remember to delete the comments!

If you go with **multiple comment tables**, you get FK constraints and cascade deletion, but you have a "wet" schema (you are repeating yourself).  For example, each comment table might have a commentbody column.  If you change that column definition, you have to change it in every comment table!

One interesting solution for a DRY-er schema could involve **table inheritance** (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/ddl-inherit.html) but please read section 5.8.1. Caveats, as there are some "gotchas" regarding indexing, at least in postgres.

Either way, kudos to you for thinking carefully about your database design!

Answer (score 2):

In term of application Design having one unique table for all coments seems to make sense. In term of application code that mean the same SQL will be reused for all entities. It's the 'classical way' used by most applications, extending on having the same acitive records and controllers used to handle comments and attachments for all objects.

In term of SQL thesecond solution could be usefull in some databases like MySQL to get more **Memory Cache** benefit. Every comment/attachmlent added in the 1st solution would drop from the memory cache all requests impacting the comment table. With individual tables a comment on one entity would not invalidate queries on other entities. But you would alos require more file descriptors and a bigger table cache.... so to choose this solution you would need a decision based on real-life, precise, case, where you would be able to compare the benefits in database access speed. And when you will add new entities you'll certainly find your each-entity-have-a-comment-table solution boring, things could have been automated by using 1st solution.

Comment: +1 - For what it's worth (unless I had specific reason to do otherwise) I'd start with option one: there's no point over engineering without solid reason.